# Powershell Multiple Arrays (noob)

Tags: loops, powershell

So say I have 2 arrays.

```
$Letters = ("A","B","C")
$Numbers = ("1","2","3")
```

How would you construct a foreach loop such that this worked:

```
foreach ($letter in $letters) {set-something $number} where I could do a pair of values such that
```

`A` was set to `1`, `B` was set to `2`, `C` was set to `3`, and so on.  What is this even called?  I thought it was called nested loops, but searching all over and it seems like that is NOT what this is called.  Many thanks!

Comment: This is called [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)ing the two lists. Not sure of the exact syntax to do it in powershell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a Zip op then this will do the trick:

```
C:\PS> $Letters | Foreach {$i=0} {@($_,$Numbers[$i++]}
A
1
B
2
C
3
```

But I think you might want this:

```
C:\PS> $Letters | Foreach {$i=0;$ht=@{}} {$ht."$_"=$Numbers[$i++]}
C:\PS> $ht.A
1
C:\PS> $ht.B
2
C:\PS> $ht.C
3
```

Comment: That seems to work, however how to I capture the "Value" and use it in a command?  For example say I wanted to write-host "$Letters = $Numbers"

Comment: Thank you!  I'm guessing $ht stands for hash table?  I'm trying to learn this language from zero scripting beyond batch/shell scripting.  I've been tasked to develop build scripts for our IIS web servers pulling all the data from an external config database.  :)

Comment: Yes, $ht is just a variable name but I tend to use it for temp hashtables.